# Factorization of a prime ideal in a integral extension.

Tags: ring-theory, prime-factorization, dedekind-domain

If $R\subseteq R'$ are integral extensions of Dedekind rings, and  $0\neq\mathfrak p$  is a prime ideal of $R$ then $R'\mathfrak p\neq R'$.

Do you know an example $R'\mathfrak p=R'$?. Of course $R\subseteq R'$ is not integral.

Thank you all.

Comment: Take $R$ = any integral domain and $R^{\prime}$ = Field of fractions of $R$. Now take any non-zero prime ideal of $R$. More specifically, $R= k[x]$ and $p = (X)$ where $k$ is any field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does $R=\Bbb Z$, $R'=\Bbb Z[\frac17]$, and $\mathfrak p=7\Bbb Z$ work?